# Python: список цифр -> все возможные числа

Tags: python, сортировка, числа

Есть список цифр. Нужна функция, которая создаст список всех возможных чисел и вернёт минимальное из них. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Пример:

ввод: `list_of_nums = ["4", "9", "7", "1"]`

вывод: `1479` в виде целого числа

Comment: Пример ввода/вывода прикрепите

Comment: ввод: list_of_nums = ["4", "9", "7", "1"]

Comment: вывод: 1479 в виде целого числа

Comment: вернёт минимальное и предполагаемый вывод - противоречат друг другу

Comment: Есть подозрение, что обязательно должны быть использованы _все_ цифры, поданные на вход.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
l = ["1","7","9","4"]
print(int(''.join(sorted(l))))  # 1479
```

Comment: Да, точно. Только что сам до этого додумался. Спасибо!

Comment: Господи, я подумал что нужно скомбинировать эти числа во все возможные комбинации... :(

Comment: @Alban я так же подумал.

Comment: Простите за плохую формулировку вопроса...

Comment: Я не вполне уверен, что согласно корректной постановке задачи, если на вход подается 0, 1 и 2 верным ответом будет "12". Но это, конечно, пальцем в небо.